# How to write a guard clause with multiple conditions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, guard-clause

After running Rubocop against this code I am getting

```
Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression.
```

So from what I have read a "Guard Clause" will bail out of the method if the condition is not met, so we don't have to waste time going through extra conditionals, please correct me if my understanding is not correct.

My question is though how would i use a guard statement with multiple conditions

```
def auth_creds
  if %w(test1 qa demo ci).include? ENV['ENV']
    { key: 'key1', secret: 'secret1' }
  elsif ENV['ENV'] == 'live'
    { key: 'key2', secret: 'secret2' }
  else
    fail 'Unable to set key/secret'
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: "*running Rubocop against this code*" - is it really *this* code? I don't get that message.

Answer (score 8):

Your snippet is not a valid example for "guard clauses". There's nothing to guard against. It's just selecting data. It'd look better as `case/when` but `if` chain is fine too.

```
def auth_creds
  case ENV['ENV']
  when 'test1', 'qa', 'demo', 'ci'
    { key: 'key1', secret: 'secret1' }
  when 'live'
    { key: 'key2', secret: 'secret2' }
  else
    fail 'Unable to set key/secret'
  end
end
```

Guard clause (or as I call them, early returns) are used when the whole body of the method is wrapped in a conditional.

```
def process_project
  if project
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

The method won't do anything unless there's a `project`. So it makes for more readable code if we reduce the nesting here.

```
def process_project
  return unless project

  # do stuff with project
end
```

Again, not every `if` in your code can/should be transformed to this form. Only where it's appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting confused as to why I would bail out of the method if the first condition was not met, I will leave it as it is, I guess I will have to turn off `Style/GuardClause` once i have checked them all

Comment: *"There's nothing to guard against"* - well, you could check that `ENV` has a `'ENV'` key and that `ENV['ENV']` has a valid value.

Comment: @Stefan: well, both of these are also covered by the conditions. No need to make a redundant check, I think.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev instead of a duplicate check, I would *move* the check  into the guard clause. See my answer (too much code for a comment).

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on your actual code, but with the given snippet, you could use a guard clause to ensure a valid `ENV['ENV']` value:

```
VALID_ENVS = %w(test1 qa demo ci live)

def auth_creds
  fail 'invalid environment' unless VALID_ENVS.include? ENV['ENV']

  if ENV['ENV'] == 'live'
    { key: 'key2', secret: 'secret2' }
  else
    { key: 'key1', secret: 'secret1' }
  end
end
```

As [noted by Sergio Tulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32473525/how-to-write-a-guard-clause-with-multiple-conditions-in-ruby#comment52809956_32474308), storing your credentials in `ENV` (instead of the env's name) would probably be better:

```
def auth_creds
  { key: ENV.fetch('KEY'), secret: ENV.fetch('SECRET') }
end
```

`fetch` will raise a `KeyError` if the given key is not found in `ENV`.

Comment: Not sure I'd write something like this in my code. I think I'd choose either a `case/when` (obvious which env corresponds to which creds, no mental compilation needed) or grab the creds directly from ENV, without branching (12-factor app best practice)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's just an example and the OP's actual code probably looks different. But of course, storing the credentials in `ENV` is much better, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Guard clauses generally go like this:

```
def do_something
  return 'x' if some_condition?
  # other code
end
```

So your code could be rewritten as

```
def auth_creds
  return { key: 'key1', secret: 'secret1' } if %w(test1 qa demo ci).include? ENV['ENV']
  return { key: 'key2', secret: 'secret2' } if ENV['ENV'] == 'live'

  fail 'Unable to set key/secret'
end
```

However, this is quite ugly, and now rubocop will complain about lines that are too long. So let us reword the code to describe its intention:

```
def auth_creds
  return { key: 'key1', secret: 'secret1' } if test_env?
  return { key: 'key2', secret: 'secret2' } if live_env?

  fail 'Unable to set key/secret'
end

private # omit if `auth_creds` is also private

def test_env?
  %w(test1 qa demo ci).include? ENV['ENV']
end

def live_env?
  ENV['ENV'] == 'live'
end
```

**Bonus Points:** Extract `%w(test1 qa demo ci)` into a constant!

**Double Bonus Points:** (thanks @Sergio Tulentsev) Get your environment-specific (and probably sensitive!!!) credentials out of your code! If using Rails, put it in a `secrets.yml`, else use one of the many great gems for this:

- [dotenv](https://rubygems.org/gems/dotenv)
- [figaro](https://rubygems.org/gems/figaro)
- ...

---

**A word about Rubocop:** Take its advice with a grain of Salt. For example, your code is not really a case for a guard clause, it's just returning data based on conditions. So instead you could also try refactoring the code as a [case expression](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#S5).

And sometime, Rubocop just talks trash :-) (not on purpose, but "measuring" code style is hard!)

Comment: For double bonus points, extract the whole thing into ENV vars, so that credentials are not stored in the code. :)